# How to generate int field with hex constant vale with codeModel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I am attempting to generate java enums using `compile group: 'com.sun.codemodel', name: 'codemodel', version: '2.6'`

Each enum constant has two int arguments that must be set to hex/unicode values.

The code I wish to generate will resemble this

```
public enum MY_ENUM {

    VALUE_0000(0x00, 0x0000),
    VALUE_0001(0x01, 0x0001),
    VALUE_0002(0x02, 0x0002),
    VALUE_0003(0x03, 0x0003);

    private final int first;
    private final int second;

    private MY_ENUM(final int first, final int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int get_first() {
        return first;
    }

    public int get_second() {
        return second;
    }

}
```

Currently all I can generate is this

```
public enum MY_ENUM {

    VALUE_0000("0x00", "0x0000"),
    VALUE_0001("0x01", "0x0001"),
    VALUE_0002("0x02", "0x0002"),
    VALUE_0003("0x03", "0x0003");

    private final int first;
    private final int second;

    private MY_ENUM(final int first, final int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int get_first() {
        return first;
    }

    public int get_second() {
        return second;
    }

}
```

The codeModel code I am employing to generate each constant is this:-

```
final String[] rawTextDataParts = rawTextDataLine.split(",");

JEnumConstant enumConst = jDefinedClass.enumConstant(generateEnumConstantName(rawTextDataParts[4]));
enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(rawTextDataParts[0]));
enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(rawTextDataParts[1]));
```

I understand that its my use of `com.sun.codemodel.JExpr` method

```
public static JExpression lit(String s)
```

that cause the issue, however I cannot see how to generate the require integer constant from the hex value.

Is it possible to achieve my desired result?

UPDATE

I have the following input data that is driving my code generation

```
0x00,   0x0000,  VALUE_0000
0x01,   0x0001,  VALUE_0001
0x02,   0x0002,  VALUE_0002
0x03,   0x0003,  VALUE_0003
```

Comment: why downvote this question? please leave a comment next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to code your numbers as hex constants. Plain `ints` will do, ie

```
VALUE_0000(0,0) // identical to VALUE_0000(0x00, 0x0000)
```

Try this:

```
enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(Integer.parseInt(rawTextDataParts[0].replaceAll("0x",""))));
enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(Integer.parseInt(rawTextDataParts[1].replaceAll("0x",""))));
```

Comment: I have updated my question, using your code with my input data gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x00"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: As my input data consists of hex values I hd to amend your fix to enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(Integer.parseInt(rawTextDataParts[0].replaceAll("0x",""), 16)));
  enumConst.arg(JExpr.lit(Integer.parseInt(rawTextDataParts[1].replaceAll("0x",""), 16)));

Comment: Did you consider using Integer.decode ? That way you don't have to edit your string.